# Different results between Whitebox Tools (WBT) and Whitebox Workflows (WBW)

Tags: watershed, whitebox-gat, whitebox-tools

I have two scripts that share the same input and use the same tools from Whitebox Toolbox. One script is written with Whitebox Workflows for Python (https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/manual/wbw-user-manual/book/getting_started.html), and the other one uses WhiteboxTools (https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/manual/wbt_book/preface.html). I am getting different results.

Shouldn't I expect the get same results?

Script 1

```
import os
from whitebox_workflows import WbEnvironment

# Initialize WhiteboxTools
wbe = WbEnvironment()

def join_path(*args):
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), *args)


# Define directories
exe_dir = join_path('WBT')
data_dir = join_path('data')
out_dir = join_path('results', 'wbw')

wbe.working_directory = out_dir

# Create a dictionary to store variables and their names
raster_dict = {}

# Reading input data
dem_path = join_path(data_dir, "dem_clipped.tif")
tezg_path = join_path(data_dir, 'TEZG_Fratnikbach.shp')
gerinne_path = join_path(data_dir, 'Bachlauf_Fratnikbach.shp')

in_dem = wbe.read_raster(dem_path)
in_tezg = wbe.read_vector(tezg_path)
in_gerinne = wbe.read_vector(gerinne_path)

# Clip raster to polygon
wbe_demCLP = wbe.clip_raster_to_polygon(
        in_dem,
        in_tezg,
        maintain_dimensions=True
    )
raster_dict['wbe_demCLP'] = wbe_demCLP
wbe.write_raster(wbe_demCLP, 'wbe_demCLP')

# Create hydrologically corrected DEM
# - Similar to "saga:fillsinkswangliu"
wbe_dgm_filled = wbe.fill_depressions_wang_and_liu(
    wbe_demCLP,
    fix_flats=True,
    flat_increment=None
  )
raster_dict['wbe_dgm_filled'] = wbe_dgm_filled

# wbe_dgm_filled_v2 = wbe.fill_depressions(
#     wbe_demCLP,
#     fix_flats=False,
#     flat_increment=None
#   )
# raster_dict['wbe_dgm_filled_v2'] = wbe_dgm_filled_v2


#  Calculate flow accumulation raster - Perform D8 flow accumulation
# - Similar to saga:catchmentarearecursive
wbe_dgm_flowacc = wbe.d8_flow_accum(
    wbe_dgm_filled,
    out_type="cells",
    clip=False,
    esri_pntr=False
)
wbe.write_raster(wbe_dgm_flowacc, 'wbe_dgm_flowacc')

# Reclassify D8 flow accumulation values to get ridges
# - Similar to "saga:reclassifyvalues"
max_value = wbe.read_raster(r"C:\workspace\ZEMOKOST_WBT\results\wbw\wbe_dgm_flowacc.tif").configs.maximum
reclass_vals = [[1, 0, 3], [0, 2, max_value]]

wbe_dgm_flowacc_reclassed = wbe.reclass(
    wbe_dgm_flowacc,
    reclass_vals,
    assign_mode=False,
)
raster_dict['wbe_dgm_flowacc_reclassed'] = wbe_dgm_flowacc_reclassed


# Set nodata value in the reclassified raster
wbe_dgm_flowacc_Ridges = wbe.set_nodata_value(
    wbe_dgm_flowacc_reclassed,
    back_value=0
)
raster_dict['wbe_dgm_flowacc_Ridges'] = wbe_dgm_flowacc_Ridges

# # --- OVERLAND FLOW LENGTH AT RIDGES---

# Rasterize stream
# - Similar to "saga:rasterize"
wbe_rasDrain = wbe.rasterize_streams(
    in_gerinne,
    wbe_dgm_filled
)
raster_dict['wbe_rasDrain'] = wbe_rasDrain

# Calculate overland flow length
# - Similar to saga:overlandflowdistancetochannelnetwor
wbe_dgm_flowlength = wbe.downslope_distance_to_stream(
    wbe_dgm_filled,
    wbe_rasDrain,
    use_dinf = False
)
raster_dict['wbe_dgm_flowlength'] = wbe_dgm_flowlength

# Multiply reclassified flowacc with flow length to overland flow length ridges
# - Similar to "saga:rastercalculator",
wbe_dgm_flowlength_Ridges= wbe.raster_calculator(
    f'"{wbe_dgm_flowlength}" * "{wbe_dgm_flowacc_Ridges}"',  [wbe_dgm_flowlength, wbe_dgm_flowacc_Ridges]
)
raster_dict['wbe_dgm_flowlength_Ridges'] = wbe_dgm_flowlength_Ridges

# Write output rasters
for name, raster in raster_dict.items():
    wbe.write_raster(raster, name)
```

Script 2

```
from WBT.whitebox_tools import WhiteboxTools
import os


def join_path(*args):
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), *args)


# Define directories
exe_dir = join_path('WBT')
data_dir = join_path('data')
out_dir = join_path('results_wbt')

# Initialize WhiteboxTools
wbt = WhiteboxTools()
wbt.set_whitebox_dir(exe_dir)
wbt.set_working_dir(data_dir)
wbt.set_verbose_mode(True)

# Data
in_tezg = 'TEZG_Fratnikbach.shp'
in_dem = 'dem_clipped.tif'
in_gerinne = 'Bachlauf_Fratnikbach.shp'

# Clip raster to polygon
wbt.clip_raster_to_polygon(
    i=in_dem,
    polygons=in_tezg,
    output=join_path(out_dir, 'wbt_demCLP.tif'),
    maintain_dimensions=True,
)

# Create hydrologically corrected DEM
wbt.fill_depressions_wang_and_liu(
    dem=join_path(out_dir, 'wbt_demCLP.tif'),
    output=join_path(out_dir, 'wbt_dgm1m_filled.tif'),
    fix_flats=True,
    flat_increment=None
)

#  Calculate flow accumulation raster - Perform D8 flow accumulation
wbt.d8_flow_accumulation(
    join_path(out_dir, 'wbt_dgm1m_filled.tif'),
    output=join_path(out_dir, 'wbt_dgm1m_flowacc.tif'),
    out_type="cells",
    log=False,
    clip=False,
    pntr=False,
    esri_pntr=False,
)

# Reclassify D8 flow accumulation values to get ridges
reclass_vals = '1;0;3;0;3;max'
wbt.reclass(
    join_path(out_dir, 'wbt_dgm1m_flowacc.tif'),
    output=join_path(out_dir, 'wbt_dgm1m_flowacc_reclassed.tif'),
    reclass_vals=reclass_vals,
    assign_mode=False,
)

# Set nodata value in the reclassified raster
wbt.set_nodata_value(
    join_path(out_dir, 'wbt_dgm1m_flowacc_reclassed.tif'),
    join_path(out_dir, 'wbt_dgm1m_flowacc_reclassed_2.tif'),
    back_value=0.0
)

# # --- OVERLAND FLOW LENGTH AT RIDGES---
# Rasterize stream
wbt.rasterize_streams(
    in_gerinne,
    join_path(out_dir, 'wbt_dgm1m_filled.tif'),
    join_path(out_dir, 'wbt_rasDrain.tif'),
    feature_id=False,
)

# Calculate overland flow length
wbt.downslope_distance_to_stream(
    join_path(out_dir, 'wbt_dgm1m_filled.tif'),
    join_path(out_dir, 'wbt_rasDrain.tif'),
    join_path(out_dir, 'wbt_dgm1m_flowlength.tif'),
    dinf=False
)

# Multiply reclassified flowacc with flow length to overland flow length ridges
wbt.raster_calculator(
    output=join_path(out_dir, 'wbt_dgm1m_flowlength_Ridges.tif'),
    statement=f'"{join_path(out_dir, "wbt_dgm1m_flowlength.tif")}" * "{join_path(out_dir, "wbt_dgm1m_flowacc_reclassed_2.tif")}"'
)
```